# Multiple Tomcat instances running with success, then Tomcat 8.0 Server does not launch

Tags: tomcat8

I am using eclipse on Windows and currently have deployed two different servers on a Tomcat 6.0 instance. This works. They are set so that their ports do not coincide. I have a Tomcat 7.0 instance and it also can be launched. Again, ports do not coincide.

I am trying to start a Tomcat 8.0 instance and this one is fighting me.

[image: Server Configuration]

It seems to me that I have specified that I should be using the ports you see above, 8015, 8019 and 1090. Yet, the log information (upon trying to start the server by running server.bat), says otherwise.

Any ideas?

- ray

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 9 2016 08:48:39 UTC
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.641 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.39.0
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.641 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.643 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b18
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.643 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.647 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\conf\logging.properties
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\endorsed
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.654 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\temp
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.655 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.2.
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:29.656 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.877 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.890 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
   java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:471)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:760)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.896 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          ... 12 more
  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:471)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:760)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
          ... 13 more

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.903 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.905 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
   java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:471)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:760)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.910 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
          ... 12 more
  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:471)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:760)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
          ... 13 more

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.917 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1718 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.948 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.949 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:30.962 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\docs
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.393 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\docs has finished in 431 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.394 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\examples
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.935 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\examples has finished in 541 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.936 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\host-manager
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.977 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\host-manager has finished in 41 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:31.978 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\manager
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.018 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\manager has finished in 40 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.019 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\ROOT
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\ROOT has finished in 28 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1131 ms
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.061 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
          at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
          at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:438)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:717)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:663)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
          at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.063 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.064 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.065 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.088 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.089 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.090 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
  18-Jan-2017 13:18:32.090 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that if you are running an Angular app in a Tomcat container, you can tell the Tomcat container which port you are using, but the Angular part of the application can disagree. Now we have:

```
$ more src/main/resources/application.properties
missing.file=Please select a file.
protocol=http
hostname=localhost
port=9080
baseUrl=rest
FILER_HOME=/Applications/CF_Files
FILER_UPLOAD_LOCATION=/Applications/CF_Files/archive
META_DATA_FILE_NAME=metadata.properties
```

and the Server is configured to use 9080 and it works and the other applications run also.